# In Python, how would you write a regex that matches the following?

Tags: python, regex, string

The string contains one or more "@" symbols.  One or more of those symbols must have a character after it (not a space).

Comment: You should give it a try yourself and post your effort.

Comment: Come oooon, you can learn to do that with a 5-minute introduction to Regular Expressions! As Greg said, give it a try!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
my_regex = re.compile(r'@\S+')
```

The `\S` class matches any non-whitespace character. If you'd prefer only alphanumeric characters, you might want to use `\w` instead.

Then, if you wanted to get all of the instances where it matched:

```
for match in my_regex.finditer(string_to_search):
    # Do something with the MatchObject in 'match'
```

More details on `finditer` are available here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'@+\S+')
```

This pattern follows the question's spec more closely: "one or more "@" symbols"